# What is the difference between := and = operators?

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between `:=` and `=` operators in MySql?

And which place is it stable to use these two?

Is it the same or just an alternative?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From your other question I know that you mean in the use case of

```
SELECT variable = column FROM table;
```

Go ahead and see for yourself...

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1), (2), (3);

SET @asdf = 2; 
SET @asdf := 2; /*those are the same*/
/*As SET is always an assignment operation, it doesn't matter here if you write it with := or with =*/
SELECT id, @asdf, @asdf = id FROM foo;
```

returns

```
+------+-------+------------+
| id   | @asdf | @asdf = id |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 |     2 |          0 |
|    2 |     2 |          1 |
|    3 |     2 |          0 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

In the result a `0` in the last column equals `false`, a `1` equals `true`.

```
SELECT @asdf := id FROM foo;
```

returns

```
+-------------+
| @asdf := id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           3 |
+-------------+
```

because the value of `id` gets assigned to the variable `@asdf`

If you now issue a

```
SELECT @asdf;
```

it returns

```
+-------+
| @asdf |
+-------+
|     3 |
+-------+
```

because the row containing `3` was last selected.

```
SELECT @asdf := id FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC;
```

returns

```
+-------------+
| @asdf := id |
+-------------+
|           3 |
|           2 |
|           1 |
+-------------+
```

Now

```
SELECT @asdf;
```

returns

```
+-------+
| @asdf |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```

Difference is clear now?

Comment: So what's the conclusion?

Answer (score 20):

### Answer

In a `SET` statement, both `:=` and `=` are assignment operators.

In a `SELECT` statement, `:=` is an assignment operator and `=` is an equality operator.

### Example

```
SET @a = 1, @b := 2;
SELECT @a, @b;   -- 1, 2
SELECT @a = @b;  -- 0 (false)

SELECT @a := @b; -- 2
SELECT @a, @b;   -- 2, 2
SELECT @a = @b;  -- 1 (true)
```